# how to get path after saving through gallery saver in flutter

Tags: flutter

#beginner
how to get image path stored through gallery_saver packege in flutter

```
 decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      suffixIcon: InkWell(
                        onTap: () async {
                          final snackBar = SnackBar(
                            content: Text('Video Uploading'),
                          );
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                          File v = File(widget.path);
                          File videoFile = File(v.path);

                          print('Recorder audio: $videoFile');
                      var response =   await GallerySaver.saveVideo(widget.path, albumName: "consolidated");
                          print("Nischal : $response");
                          
                        
                          context.pop();
```

i am get a boolen from stored file

```
/flutter (31440): Recorder audio: File: '/data/user/0/com.mycompany.consolidated/cache/REC7346318815602084408.mp4'
I/flutter (31440): Nischal : true
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. I was unable to retrieve a path from [gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver/example). I ended up using [image_gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver/example). It returns a boolean value as well, however you can specify the save path. Since you have the `savePath` variable you can use that depending on your use case.

In my use case I needed to share a video. In order to share it with the package we were using we first had to save the video and then use the savePath to locate and share the file.

Here is what an example looks like to save media using this package:

```
var appDocDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      savePath = "${appDocDir.path}/${video.name}";
      await Dio().download(video.url, savePath);
      await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(savePath);
```

Note: To copy this example you will need the [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio/install) and [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/install) packages.

In this example we use `getTemporaryDirectory()` and use that to create a `savePath` variable. We use the video name, i.e. 'video.mp4', as a unique extension to the path. We use `Dio` to download the video from the url (this can be done with local media as well. See package for details), we then use `image_gallery_saver` to save the video to the device. We can now successfully save the video and we have the path for further use cases.